# Can't retrieve the right number of objects from an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

**What I'm Doing:**

I'm using CoreData to store information for my app. The most logical way to do this in my instance is to use indexPaths with 3 dimensions, like so:

```
unsigned indexes[3] = {week, day, position};
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:3];
return [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Firstly, is this OK - or should objects strictly be stored in a two dimensional indexPath?

---

**Where I get stuck:**

If it is OK to do this, how can I fix the following method:

```
- (int)numEventsForWeek:(UInt8)week day:(dayOfWeek)day;
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:week] objectAtIndex:day];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

This currently crashes because of an unrecognized selector error (the second objectAtIndex:) - But if I take out the second objectAtIndex:, sectionInfo will only give me the number of objects narrowed down to the second index dimension (which is too many objects, I need the number narrowed down to the third dimension).

Comment: Could you explain the backing core data model?

Comment: @VinceBurn it consists of a single Entity (+ associated class) with only a handful of properties. This entity/class represents an event, and I am trying to store/access them based on the week and day of week that they occur (events are monthly). After some more research it looks like I can only use multidimensional indexes though if I implement a section name key path for the fetched results controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a predicate to filter the result you want to have?
Like a predicate for a specific month, week and weekday.

Can you take a screen shot of your entity?
I might have an other idea...

Comment: Thanks - I never realized there was such a thing as a predicate filter until now. After a bit of googling, it looks like this is a much more logical way to achieve what I want - cheers.